# a tetraquaternionic magma

Tags: abstract-algebra, mathematical-physics, quaternions

In Clifford algebras over $\mathbb R$ you look at directions squaring to $-1$ or $+1$.
Made me wonder:  Why does not nature encode source information yet another way: $(\sqrt i)^2=i$ so that $i^4=j^4=-1$?
Still keeping quaternions' associativity and chirality $ji=-ij$ so that $$i^vj^wi^mj^n=(-1)^{wm+\lfloor\frac{v+w}4\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{m+n}4\rfloor}i^{(v+m)\%4}j^{(w+n)\%4},$$I [arrive](https://tio.run/##XY7LDoIwEEX3fEUzsigWiIks5Q905bJBMwUMU3lFqm7499oghOjuZs49N1PhcC/r2lqJFKLONlJRqHSWgg9CeIxxurGuKDjqrSJR0IsjCUVB8s1aKB0kganKFiIo66EECCYR6OIWhqp786YrFmtm@pfNK0KAPwJzBca8BqlNG@xPV9Y/zdk8jq2E0Wl51@Zo5N/Do7MUHSK5i@N95i5LnAiuBFfiWfsB) at the following tetraquaternionic (name clash with Patrick Girard's!) multiplication table:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $i^0j^0$ | $i^0j^1$ | $i^0j^2$ | $i^0j^3$ | $i^1j^0$ | $i^1j^1$ | $i^1j^2$ | $i^1j^3$ | $i^2j^0$ | $i^2j^1$ | $i^2j^2$ | $i^2j^3$ | $i^3j^0$ | $i^3j^1$ | $i^3j^2$ | $i^3j^3$ |
| $i^0j^1$ | $i^0j^2$ | $i^0j^3$ | $-i^0j^0$ | $-i^1j^1$ | $-i^1j^2$ | $-i^1j^3$ | $i^1j^0$ | $i^2j^1$ | $i^2j^2$ | $i^2j^3$ | $-i^2j^0$ | $-i^3j^1$ | $-i^3j^2$ | $-i^3j^3$ | $i^3j^0$ |
| $i^0j^2$ | $i^0j^3$ | $-i^0j^0$ | $-i^0j^1$ | $i^1j^2$ | $i^1j^3$ | $-i^1j^0$ | $-i^1j^1$ | $i^2j^2$ | $i^2j^3$ | $-i^2j^0$ | $-i^2j^1$ | $i^3j^2$ | $i^3j^3$ | $-i^3j^0$ | $-i^3j^1$ |
| $i^0j^3$ | $-i^0j^0$ | $-i^0j^1$ | $-i^0j^2$ | $-i^1j^3$ | $i^1j^0$ | $i^1j^1$ | $i^1j^2$ | $i^2j^3$ | $-i^2j^0$ | $-i^2j^1$ | $-i^2j^2$ | $-i^3j^3$ | $i^3j^0$ | $i^3j^1$ | $i^3j^2$ |
| $i^1j^0$ | $i^1j^1$ | $i^1j^2$ | $i^1j^3$ | $i^2j^0$ | $i^2j^1$ | $i^2j^2$ | $i^2j^3$ | $i^3j^0$ | $i^3j^1$ | $i^3j^2$ | $i^3j^3$ | $-i^0j^0$ | $-i^0j^1$ | $-i^0j^2$ | $-i^0j^3$ |
| $i^1j^1$ | $i^1j^2$ | $i^1j^3$ | $-i^1j^0$ | $-i^2j^1$ | $-i^2j^2$ | $-i^2j^3$ | $i^2j^0$ | $i^3j^1$ | $i^3j^2$ | $i^3j^3$ | $-i^3j^0$ | $i^0j^1$ | $i^0j^2$ | $i^0j^3$ | $-i^0j^0$ |
| $i^1j^2$ | $i^1j^3$ | $-i^1j^0$ | $-i^1j^1$ | $i^2j^2$ | $i^2j^3$ | $-i^2j^0$ | $-i^2j^1$ | $i^3j^2$ | $i^3j^3$ | $-i^3j^0$ | $-i^3j^1$ | $-i^0j^2$ | $-i^0j^3$ | $i^0j^0$ | $i^0j^1$ |
| $i^1j^3$ | $-i^1j^0$ | $-i^1j^1$ | $-i^1j^2$ | $-i^2j^3$ | $i^2j^0$ | $i^2j^1$ | $i^2j^2$ | $i^3j^3$ | $-i^3j^0$ | $-i^3j^1$ | $-i^3j^2$ | $i^0j^3$ | $-i^0j^0$ | $-i^0j^1$ | $-i^0j^2$ |
| $i^2j^0$ | $i^2j^1$ | $i^2j^2$ | $i^2j^3$ | $i^3j^0$ | $i^3j^1$ | $i^3j^2$ | $i^3j^3$ | $-i^0j^0$ | $-i^0j^1$ | $-i^0j^2$ | $-i^0j^3$ | $-i^1j^0$ | $-i^1j^1$ | $-i^1j^2$ | $-i^1j^3$ |
| $i^2j^1$ | $i^2j^2$ | $i^2j^3$ | $-i^2j^0$ | $-i^3j^1$ | $-i^3j^2$ | $-i^3j^3$ | $i^3j^0$ | $-i^0j^1$ | $-i^0j^2$ | $-i^0j^3$ | $i^0j^0$ | $i^1j^1$ | $i^1j^2$ | $i^1j^3$ | $-i^1j^0$ |
| $i^2j^2$ | $i^2j^3$ | $-i^2j^0$ | $-i^2j^1$ | $i^3j^2$ | $i^3j^3$ | $-i^3j^0$ | $-i^3j^1$ | $-i^0j^2$ | $-i^0j^3$ | $i^0j^0$ | $i^0j^1$ | $-i^1j^2$ | $-i^1j^3$ | $i^1j^0$ | $i^1j^1$ |
| $i^2j^3$ | $-i^2j^0$ | $-i^2j^1$ | $-i^2j^2$ | $-i^3j^3$ | $i^3j^0$ | $i^3j^1$ | $i^3j^2$ | $-i^0j^3$ | $i^0j^0$ | $i^0j^1$ | $i^0j^2$ | $i^1j^3$ | $-i^1j^0$ | $-i^1j^1$ | $-i^1j^2$ |
| $i^3j^0$ | $i^3j^1$ | $i^3j^2$ | $i^3j^3$ | $-i^0j^0$ | $-i^0j^1$ | $-i^0j^2$ | $-i^0j^3$ | $-i^1j^0$ | $-i^1j^1$ | $-i^1j^2$ | $-i^1j^3$ | $-i^2j^0$ | $-i^2j^1$ | $-i^2j^2$ | $-i^2j^3$ |
| $i^3j^1$ | $i^3j^2$ | $i^3j^3$ | $-i^3j^0$ | $i^0j^1$ | $i^0j^2$ | $i^0j^3$ | $-i^0j^0$ | $-i^1j^1$ | $-i^1j^2$ | $-i^1j^3$ | $i^1j^0$ | $i^2j^1$ | $i^2j^2$ | $i^2j^3$ | $-i^2j^0$ |
| $i^3j^2$ | $i^3j^3$ | $-i^3j^0$ | $-i^3j^1$ | $-i^0j^2$ | $-i^0j^3$ | $i^0j^0$ | $i^0j^1$ | $-i^1j^2$ | $-i^1j^3$ | $i^1j^0$ | $i^1j^1$ | $-i^2j^2$ | $-i^2j^3$ | $i^2j^0$ | $i^2j^1$ |
| $i^3j^3$ | $-i^3j^0$ | $-i^3j^1$ | $-i^3j^2$ | $i^0j^3$ | $-i^0j^0$ | $-i^0j^1$ | $-i^0j^2$ | $-i^1j^3$ | $i^1j^0$ | $i^1j^1$ | $i^1j^2$ | $i^2j^3$ | $-i^2j^0$ | $-i^2j^1$ | $-i^2j^2$ |

I am playing in a Zusean [RechnenderRaum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculating_Space) grid.  I want to test if tetraquaternionically satisfying the quite Einsteinian-looking Maxwell difference equations [$\{\delta,\{\delta,\omega\}\}+[\delta,[\delta,\omega]]$](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0307038.pdf) thermomagnetically balancing decelerating mass and accelerating curvature magically spits out Schrödinger imaginary squares and Pythagorean square roots.

**Question**: With a neutral, and inverses for all 32 elements, $(T\cup-T,\cdot)$ seems to be a group. What is it named from the catalog of finite groups?

Please help me out with your insights and vocabulary!

Comment: Ummm.... what does "nature" have to do with anything here?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Clifford algebras so I won't post an answer, but posts are meant to ask only one question. Maybe two is acceptable, but you're asking five different questions in the same post, which could lead to downvotes or people voting to close the post. I know you spent time writing the post, but I would edit it such that it only asks one question, especially since it seems like some of those questions can easily be answered by anyone who knows about basic abstract algebra.

Comment: See [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_32) for the nonabelian groups of order $32$ (among them generalised quaternion group $Q_{32}$, dihedral group $D_{16}$, semidihedral group $SD_{16}$ etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [semidirect product of $\mathbb Z_8$ and $\mathbb Z_4$ of $M$-type](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Semidirect_product_of_Z8_and_Z4_of_M-type).

The condition $G=\langle a,b\mid a^8=b^4=e,bab^{-1}=a^5\rangle$ is met by $$T\cup-T=\langle i, ij \mid i^8=1=(ij)^4,(ij)i(ij)^{-1}=(ij)i(-i^3j^3)=i^5\rangle.$$